# Showing that inequality holds with high probabilty

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

$X=\sum_{i=1}^{n^2} X_{i}$ random variable. $E[X]=\frac{n^2}{a(n)}$.

For which $a$, $X \geq n\cdot C$ holds with high probability? So the following: $P(X\geq n\cdot C)= 1-o(1)$.

What would be an approach for that problem?

(To get a feeling I solved $\frac{n^2}{a}>nC$ and get a < n/C, how to proceed from here?)

Comment: any assumption on $X_i$ ?

Comment: $X_{i} = 1$ with probability $1/a$, otherwise 0 and the $X_{i}$ are independent